# Python Unittest: Fail due to import from same folder

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, import

the question seems pretty trivial, but I could not find a single answer to it online. Heres my setup:

```
project:
- src:
- - __init__.py (empty)
- - file1.py
- - file2.py
- test:
- - test1.py
- - test2.py
- - __init__.py (empty)
```

Now, I want to run

```
python -m unittest discover
```

from the project folder.

In test1.py I import and import from my first source file:

```
from src.file1 import class1
```

In file1.py however, I import from the other one:

```
from file2 import class2
```

Running the unittest as mentioned above results in:

```
[...]
    from file2 import class2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: I think you just want to do `from src.file2 import class2` in your file1.py

Comment: That gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'` when I try to call  file1.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fully qualify your imports, i.e. instead of:

```
from file2 import class2
```

use

```
from .file2 import class2
```

notice the `.` after `from`.

**Update:** verification:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> tree
.
|-- src
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- file1.py
|   `-- file2.py
`-- test
    |-- __init__.py
    `-- test1.py

2 directories, 5 files

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> type src\file1.py

from .file2 import Class2

class class1:
    pass

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> type src\file2.py


class Class2:
    pass

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> type test\test1.py

from src.file1 import class1

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> python -m unittest discover

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project>
```

Notice that I'm running the command from a directory where `from src.xxx` makes sense.

**Update 2:** Note, Python does not cater to running individual files in a subdirectory directly (i.e. as an entry point). Guido is strongly against such usage so this is unlikely to change.  While you can hack your way around this, doing it the right way is very simple and worth learning.

Let's first change `src/file1.py` to have a `main()` function:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> cat src\file1.py

from .file2 import Class2

class class1:
    pass


def main():
    print("hello from main")
```

Note: I'm not adding a `if __name__=="__main__"` section.

The right way of calling this function from the command line is to make `project` a "real" package.

A "real" package is created by adding a `setup.py` file. `setup.py` files can contain a lot of fields, but the only ones needed for this use-case are as follows:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> cat setup.py

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="myproject",
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': """
            run-file1 = src.file1:main
        """
    }
)
```

note that `setup.py` lives in the `project` folder.

Next you install your package in "development" mode:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> pip install -e .
```

notice the `.` at the end.

The entry_points .. console_scripts in the `setup.py` file has now created a new shell command for you:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\tmp\unttst\project> run-file1
hello from main
```

the console_scripts line

```
run-file1 = src.file1:main
```

says to create a shell command named `run-file` which should execute the `main` function found in `src.file1`.

Comment: That gives me     from .file2 import Class2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.file2'; '__main__' is not a package` when I try to call file1.py.

Comment: @DisplayName I've updated my answer with verification.

Comment: Yes, for the testing the import works now. But when I call e.g. `python src/file1.py` (for example because there is a main function that I want to use), I get the error that I posted in the above comment. There are some threads about this error on stackoverflow, with the base recommendation being "dont use relative imports". So how would one get to use both?

Comment: @DisplayName I've updated my answer with instructions on how to call entry points in files found in subdirectories from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for claring things up!