# python import local module from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have the following structure:

```
root/
    folder1/
        main.py
        secondary.py
    folder2/
        test.py
```

the `main.py` code always runs from the `root` folder, so on the `main.py` I have an

```
from folder1.secondary import *
```

so I can use its functions on `main.py` - that works fine

on `tests.py`, I do:

```
from root.folder1.main import myfunction
```

(that is the only function I need to test) but it fails saying `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1.secondary'`

`root` is on `sys.path`

I dont understand why importing `main.py` directly works but importing from another folder doesn't. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can import locally from a script (i.e. when you run `main.py` directly) but not from a module. You need to change `main.py` to an absolute import as well: `from root.folder1 import *`

Comment: (when you `from root.folder1.main import ...` then `main` is treated as a module)

Comment: Your question seems similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793765/python-unittest-fail-due-to-import-from-same-folder/54793814#54793814

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have a file called `__init__.py` in each directory so the Python interpreters treats that directory as a module it can import things from. The file can be empty but it has to be named like that.

Your new directory structure would look like:

```
root/
    __init__.py
    folder1/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        secondary.py
    folder2/
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

Then you can import your `main.py` in the `test.py` by doing `from root.folder1.main import myfunction`.